# Add a delivery time based on custom fields calculations for WooCommerce Flat rate Shipping method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I use code that displays a custom field on the product edit page. This text box shows the cooking time on the single product page.

Here is the code:

```
// Backend: Display additional product fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_time_field_general_product_data' );

function add_time_field_general_product_data() {
// Custom Time Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
    'id' => '_custom_time',
    'label' => __( 'Time for cooking', 'woocommerce' ),
));    
}

// Backend: Save the data value from the custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_time_custom_fields_values' );

function save_time_custom_fields_values( $product ) {
// Save Custom Time Field
if( isset( $_POST['_custom_time'] ) ) {
    $product->update_meta_data( '_custom_time', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_time'] ) );
}
}

// Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'custom_time_field_checkout_item_name', 10, 3 );

function custom_time_field_checkout_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
if( $value4 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_custom_time') ) {
    $item_qty .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-style"><strong>' . __("Time for cooking", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value4 . ' min.</div>';
}

return $item_qty;
}

// Display custom fields values on orders and email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_time_field_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function custom_time_field_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
$product = $item->get_product();

if( $value4 = $product->get_meta('_custom_time') ) {
    $item_name .= '<br /><span class="my-custom-style"><strong>' . __("Time for cooking", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value4 . ' min.</span>';
}

return $item_name;
}
```

How can get the following functionality based on this code?

For example, a customer adds several dishes to a cart and checkout order. He sees how much time will be cooking this or that dish.

But when the customer chooses the delivery by courier (Flat Rate), in the same block, the delivery time is shown.

Flat Rate = $10

Delivery time = (the longest cooking time is selected from the order) min. + 45 min.

As I understand it, need to get the data of the custom field '_custom_time' when placing the order. Then, somehow need to get the highest value of this field and add 45 minutes.

I ask for your help! I hope that the answer to this question will be useful to many developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following codethat will display a delivery time (calculated from the highest item cooking time value + 45 minutes) when a "flat rate" shipping method is selected on checkout page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'action_after_shipping_rate_callback', 10, 2 );
function action_after_shipping_rate_callback( $method, $index ) {
    $chosen_shipping_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[$index];

    if( is_checkout() && $method->method_id === 'flat_rate' && $method->id === $chosen_shipping_id ) {
        $extra_time = 45; // Additional time to be added
        $data_array = []; // Initializing

        // Loop through car items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $cooking_time = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_custom_time') ) {
                $data_array[] = (int) $cooking_time;
            }
        }

        if ( sizeof($data_array) ) {
            $max_time = (int) max($data_array);
            $delivery_time = $max_time + $extra_time;
            echo '<br><small style="margin-left:2em;border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:2px 5px;"><strong>' . __("Delivery time", "woocommerce") . '</strong>: ' . $delivery_time . ' min.</small>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> To enable that in cart page too, remove  **`is_checkout() &&`** from the `IF` statement.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!